# 301 Redirection not working on Query string URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wan't to redirect independently query string URL without affecting rest of redirection.

I used below code for that but it is not working.

```
Redirect 301 /contact/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=7/  https://www.abc.xyz/contact-us.php
Redirect 301 /contact/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=7   https://www.abc.xyz/contact-us.php
```

Also I used below 301 redirection but it is redirect to `abc.xyz/page/2`

```
Redirect 301 /tag/metal-roof/page/2/    https://www.abc.xyz/solar-power.php
Redirect 301 /tag/metal-roof/page/2     https://www.abc.xyz/solar-power.php

Redirect 301 /tag/metal-roof/   https://www.abc.xyz/
Redirect 301 /tag/metal-roof    https://www.abc.xyz/
```

Comment: Here's the 1st correct regex ^/contact/index.php\?main_page=index&cPath=7/?$

Comment: Regarding the second one it's messy thing there since /tag/metal-roof/ will work for the above one as well. Use ^/tag/metal-roof/?$ and ^/tag/metal-roof/page/2/?$

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski `Redirect` does string matching only, using regular expressions would require switching to the `RedirectMatch` directive. But that still doesn’t change the fact, that both only match against the _path_ component of the URL. Redirects based on query string contents need to be made using mod_rewrite, by a combination of RewriteCond & RewriteRule.

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski thanks but given solution is not working. For 2nd solution it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using Below code at least I am able to redirect to that page but not able to remove query string.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^contact\/index\.php$ "https\:\/\/www\.abc\.xyz\/contact\-us\.php" [R=301,L]
```

After redirection URL look like :

```
https://www.abc.xyz/contact-us.php?main_page=index&cPath=7
```

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule contains an explanation of how you can get rid of the query string.